# What is the correct way to pass props (Vue/React)? Pass object or each prop separately?

Tags: reactjs, vue.js

I have the following situation, described below. What would be more correct?

In the variant with each individual property - we win, it seems, in that we cut off the random possibility of changing props from the child component and you can safely validate everything.

In the second case, everything seems to be more neatly structured, but you need to write additional validation for it, and there is a chance of accidentally modifying it from a child component.

```js
// 1

  <SolocatorHeader 
    titleText="Project Summary"
    titleColor="#FFDBCD"
    titleImg="/test.png"
    descText="Some text"
    descColor="#FFFFFF"
  />

// 2

  <SolocatorHeader
    :title="{
      text: 'Project Summary',
      color: 'FFDBCD',
      img: '/test.png'
    }"
    :desc="{
      text: 'Some text',
      color: '#FFFFFF'
    }"
  />
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Vue props: Should I pass the object or its properties? Does it make much difference?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49748813/vue-props-should-i-pass-the-object-or-its-properties-does-it-make-much-differe)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To minimize re-rendering could be good the send the props separately, depends if some of that props are going to be updated more often.

If you want to pass them the props separately but still want to not have to write the props separately, you can use the spread notation:

```
<SolocatorHeader {..title} {...desc} />
```